# Proving the convergence and divergence of the p-series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

We know from calculus that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ diverges if $p \in [0,1)$ and converges if $p > 1$. I want to use analysis to prove these two statements. For the case where $p > 1$ we know $S_{N+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{1}{n^p} > \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^p} = S_N$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$. This is because $\frac{1}{n^p} > 0$, hence the partial sums $S_{N}$ are increasing. Now if we can show $S_N$ is bounded, we would be done. But I am have trouble showing boundedness, and proving divergence case when $p \in [0,1)$.

Also I dont want to use integrals to show these results.

Comment: Try using Cauchy-Condensation Test http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: Let's take a look at: http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/harmapa.pdf then the divergence for $p \in [0,1)$ can be proved using for example the limit comparison test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-p}\text{ converges} \iff\,  \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n (2^n)^{-p}\ \text{ converges}$$
So $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \big(2^{1-p}\big)^{n}$, and the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ converges iff $|x|<1$. Thus the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-p}$ will converges iff $|2^{1-p}|<1$, which happens iff $p>1$ (try proving it without logarithms, just using elementary facts about exponentiation).